# This htaccess code not working but some others are working

Tags: php, .htaccess

This htaccess code not working but some others are working:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) category.php?cat=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: what are you intending the code to do?

Comment: Give examples of the URLs that aren't being rewritten. It is very likely that your regular expression simply doesn't match the URL.

Comment: ibj1.7/wholesale-indian-BANGLES%20AND%20BRACELETS

The problem is arising due to a space in between.

Comment: Nayan, how would the regular expression that you've written in the `RewriteRule` match the URL you've given in the comment?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried masking your slash like so?

```
^category\/([a-z]+)
```